# Export multiple actions in action.js file Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two actions in action.js file like this.

```
const addpostid = (post) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
        post
    }
}

const addcommentform = (login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
        login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent
    }
}
```

How can I export these actions?

I use `export default` but it for only one action.

Here is my dispatch :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return { 
      commentformadded: (login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent) => dispatch(addcommentform(login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent)) 
    };
  };
```

Comment: `export const addpostid`?

Comment: @Justcode It returns object error when I call from dispatch

Comment: You need explain your whole flow of dispatching then I can help you.

Comment: @Justcode can you check my updated dispatch code? Thanks

Comment: You can use export const then import whole action file as some temp variable and access it using `temp.yourfunction`

Comment: @Justcode: Can you write to answer? I am still confused. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your actions like this

```
export const addpostid = (post) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
        post
    }
}

export const addcommentform = (login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
        login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent
    }
}
```

Then assuming your file name is testActions.js

In your component you can import it like this

```
import * as testActions 'path to your action/testActions';
```

Use your  functions like this

```
testActions.addpostid
```

or

```
testActions.addcommentform
```

or

```
import { addpostid, addcommentform } from 'path to your action/testActions';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only export one value as default. However using named exports you can export as many modules as you want. You can do that like

```
const addpostid = (post) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
        post
    }
}

const addcommentform = (login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
        login_status, author_name, author_email, content, parent
    }
}

export { addpostid, addcommentform };
```

and in the files import them like

```
import { addpostid, addcommentform } from 'path/to/actions';
```

or simply import all exports from the like like

```
import * as actions from 'path/to/actions';
```

and use them like `actions.addpostid`, `actions.addcommentform`